# how to return an images to local hard drive with flask response?

Tags: python, image, flask, response

I have defined a flask api to curl an images from my remote server, and I tried to do something like:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder = 'file/path')
@app.route('/getimg', methods=['POST'])
def getimg():
    imgname = getname()
# return result
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, imgname, as_attachment=True)
```

When I try to curl this image, what I get is not an image on local disc but a bunch of meaningless string on my terminal like:

```
?PNG

IHDRl{%kIDATx???w????O???/?z?
                         U
??H?I??HER?5n??[??g??i?ǣ?eKj?8n?Hy)Q?D?H
                                     )? ?
(?rzU/???t?N?s  ?l  %?Z}V??n?????{?>???ۿ??????,???={fggw????w?{mm??h?q??????z=?2????d????p8??Xk???8??"???AĲ,???z}<?;w????kkk??{?755??????|?u?-//???5?dY?????????}??}w?qǡC??$ulll????y?+???f&"?}ǯ??#?_?Q[?{?(H??K??k???aW\???
                                                            ?[?P^??h4z????/Z?6|"ʲ_?????9r????z?????9??????'???J)?9?s"?R??(??4
 ?45??֭?1R?W?????~?c?ɟ?ɠ??<WJ@EAuEQd?5?H)??k????`f?1??RJ?}?eEQDQ??*˲?l:?F??h4
/?Z???)?w~`Y???g?!?Z-\?????FEKKK???gz?^??^^^~?[????D???>77???#?<??Oz8NNN?????p?@??  B??J)Dt?Y??;??\?yǱ?Z
```

and so on.

How can I get an image file saved to my disk?

Comment: just skip the `as_attachment` and let it default to `False`

Comment: That is what I tried before, I still got meaningless string on my terminal though.

Comment: Can you show your curl command ?

Comment: I know that, but my goal is to save this image on my local disk, not only got its binary data on my terminal

Comment: my curl commad is: curl -X POST http://serverip/getimg -F file=@/path/to/file/image.jpg what I do is to processing this image and get the new image back

Comment: add the `-o output.png` flag

Comment: -o output.png this one works well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the data from `curl` to a file. It's currently outputting the binary data in the terminal.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d  '{"filename": "cmp.png"}' http://localhost:5000/getimg > cmp.png
```

Comment: my curl commad is: curl -X POST serverip/getimg -F file=@/path/to/file/image.jpg what I wish do is to processing this local image and get the new image back from remote server

Comment: Whatever it is just use ` http://localhost:5000/getimg > cmp.png` to save into your local disk.